# What do these icons in Visual Studio and TFS mean?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We are using VS Premium 2013, TFS 2013 and I have TFS PowerTools 2013 and TFS Source Control Explorer Extension 2013 (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/af70cbb7-1e0d-4d16-bc57-cccc15370c51).

I am in the process of cleaning up old branches (delete & destroy) but some don't delete & destroy. There are 5 different branch/folder icons in VS/TFS and I can't find any info on them.

The top one is a folder. The second one is a folder with a small x. The third is a folder with a blue arrow, fourth is a branch (?) and the fifth is a big red x. What do these mean and are some of them un-deleteable?

I am project/collection administrator and I have tried giving myself explicit permissions to manage the branch (and all other permissions too).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can delete branches and folder, but they won't be physically deleted. They will only be marked as deleted and invisible unless you explicitly display deleted items.

The second and third are deleted folder.

The big X is a deleted branch.

The non-folder icons are all branches.

Comment: You can physically delete it by using the TFS API "destroy" command. Which isn't working in this case.

Comment: Why isn't it possible for you to use the command line tool to destroy the branch? What is your error message?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete a branch in TFS. Did you check your change in?

1. Right click on the branch and delete (will still appear with a red cross).
2. Then Right-click on the folder with the red cross and chose check -in Pending Changes.
   Good luck

Comment: You can't check in a change that you weren't allowed to make or couldn't make.

Comment: I eventually figured out that one image file had permission inheritance turned off. I added myself to the security list and I could delete/destroy the branch.